# Access - SQL query to make table on protected backend db

Tags: sql, ms-access, passwords, backend, overwrite

I'm stuck trying to make a simple make table query to replace an exting table on a password protected backend database.

```
SELECT MyNewTable.* INTO (MS Access;PWD=MyPassword;DATABASE=\\mydomain\shares\Myshare\Mydatabase_be.accdb) MyTable
FROM MyNewTable;
```

The first challange was finding out how to include the password, now the problem is that access simply says the table allready exists, and doesn't give me the option to overwrite it.

Would appreciate if someone could shed some light on this :)

Comment: Are you trying to execute this using VBA?  You first need to DROP the table   See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177897(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks Wayne, this worked:
Dim dbs As Database
MYDB = "\\MyDomain\shares\MyDatabase_be.accdb"
    Set dbs = OpenDatabase(MYDB, False, False, ";pwd=MyPassword" & DBPass & "")

    ' Delete the Employees table.
    dbs.Execute "DROP TABLE MyTable;"

    dbs.Close
Now the maketable query runs without problems! Thank you!